# Maintaining references for solutions across subversion

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, svn, reference, projects-and-solutions

I have one solution with three projects inside of it.  These projects are all meant to be used independently if so desired.  To give a clear picture, my projects are as follows:

- "General" class library project that contains many base abstract classes like "Person" and some Helper classes.
- "EmployeeManagement" class library project that contains classes like Employee : Person, EmployeeAddressList, and other things related to managing employees.
- A web application project that references the above two projects to act as a presentation layer/web form.  i.e. "editemployees.aspx.cs" for editing existing employee info, etc.

---

This is all fine and well, but when I make a lot of changes and then push all three projects to their three respective repositories, my co-worker will pull all of my changes from the three repositories, then open the overall solution.  Everything is there and intact, but the web application project no longer recognizes the references to General and EmployeeManagement.  They are listed in the References folder, but the code itself won't compile, screaming all sorts of underlined red madness.  The simple solution is to remove them from the References folder and then add them again, and like magic, everything just works again.

The questions I have are:

1. why does this happen?
2. what am I doing wrong?  (perhaps the order of my pushing to the repositories or the order of his pulling is off?)
3. what can I do to prevent this from happening?

Thanks :)

Comment: How are you adding the references? Are you adding a reference to the project or to a compiled DLL?

Comment: Adding references to the project, by right clicking the project in VS2010, going to "Add Reference," and choosing the projects from the Projects tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your directory layout is different than your coworker's.

Your project looks to small to justify being spread over three repos. You'd better concentrate on the architecture of your software than to make life complicated by overengineered project infrastructure.

Btw. in svn we commit and update :-)

Comment: I don't agree that size is a factor in determining the repository layout. If the class libraries are indeed shared across multiple projects or solutions then it makes perfect sense to store them in separate repositories.

Comment: Generally, you are right, but in case the OP has a hard time solving something that looks really trivial, I wouldn't recommend him playing with advanced scenarios like multi-repository setup for a single-solution development.

Comment: The reason I chose to go with three repositories is to keep these projects all independent, if they should ever be needed independently.  For example, some day, someone says, "man I wish we had a class library of general abstract classes like Person and EmailAddress, so I don't have to create all that from scratch."  Then I can just say, "oh sure, go check-out the General repository," and that's completely independent of this web application project.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt: Most likely, this will never happen, because those general classes are not as general as you might think. They are `abstract`, sure, but they are still tailored to the needs of your current project. You would be better of moving that class library to a different repository when it really will be used by different projects.

Comment: @OndrejTucny: To be pedantic, in SVN we do update and commit on a working copy.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  After considering what you said, I think you're probably right.  I was probably aiming too large, to create something that could encompass all future projects.  But if a future project ever needed it, it wouldn't be the end of the world to just copy it over and re-tailor it to that project.  And as soon as I thought that, duh, you're right, I'd be re-tailoring it anyway :)  Thanks!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Oops, thanks, I was thinking of `svn ci` and confused myself :-)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more, I would view your respective .sln and .csproj or .vbproj files, and make sure that the relative path to the included projects are not being overwritten each time one of you commits changes.

The following are examples of included project references in your solution/project files:

### .sln

```
Project("{6f8415d8-82c0-4e47-8ddd-f3962bb3b518}") = "QuickJoe.Awesome", "QuickJoe.Awesome\QuickJoe.Awesome.csproj", "{e623a940-79ba-4762-af02-84993a2b37b7}"
EndProject
Project("{6f8415d8-82c0-4e47-8ddd-f3962bb3b518}") = "QuickJoe", "..\qjs\QuickJoe\QuickJoe.csproj", "{6754372e-b253-41be-9b83-23cf8bea786f}"
EndProject
```

### .csproj/.vbproj

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\qjs\QuickJoe\QuickJoe.csproj">
    <Project>{6754372e-b253-41be-9b83-23cf8bea786f}</Project>
    <Name>QuickJoe</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Another good tip (if you are not already doing so) is to specifically exclude .user and .suo files. In some cases they are actively harmful when loaded on a different workstation.

Comment: Wow, this is something I had no idea about :) Learn something new every day.  Will definitely play with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio, consider placing your solution at the top of your folder tree, and the projects beneath that.  Visual Studio should then reference the projects via `$(SolutionDir)`, one of its internal variables.  Failing that, edit the solution by hand and make the folder/project locations relative to `$(SolutionDir)`, and then everything should be portable no matter where it is checked out.